# How do I select multiple elements and a class in JQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

So I was asked a simple question on Treehouse, but I'm confused about how to order the code.

I was asked to use jQuery to select all list items in an unordered list with the class of 'nav'. I'm not sure how to order my code (I'm literally brand new to JQuery). Here's my incorrect answer.

```
$("li ul .nav");
```

Comment: `$('li.nav')` where list item has class .nav

Comment: Does the `li` or the `ul` have the class of 'nav'?

Comment: you should always post relevant html for question regarding selector

Comment: A.Wolff, I'll try to remember that. It's a tutorial that just started so they hadn't give me much HTML to work with at that point, but I'll still make sure to always include it when possible. Also thanks to Omar for the help. David, I wasn't sure about that either, but the answer that zigdawgydawg gave me $("ul.nav li"); actually worked. Does that mean ul had the class?

Answer (score 2):

The following selects all list items in a list that has the .nav class (`<ul class="nav">...</ul>`):

```
$("ul.nav li");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot zig. That worked. I'm going to have to just do as many of these as possible until I get used to the format. This was helpful though. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('ul.nav li');
```

This selects every child li in ul with the class 'nav'.

Answer (score 0):

Ancestor elements need to be first, as jQuery looks "down" from the `<html>` element, and to select `ul`'s with a class `.nav` you need to do `ul.nav`.

```
$('ul.nav li');
```